# What is `<Value>` in `enum Result<Value> { ... }`?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

There's a enum like this:

```
enum Result<Value> {

case Success(Value)
case Failure(NSData?, ErrorType)

}
```

What's the `<Value>` part? It's not explained in the Apple documentation.

Comment: It is documented. Lookup "Generic Types" in the Swift book.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, you are fantastic, you answers several questions of mine :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a generic, [here is the doc references](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)

What is means is when you create a variable of `Result` you pass the type in `< >` brackets

e.g.

```
var res: Result<String>
```

Now your `Value` becomes `String`

And if your want that to be `Int` then you will probably do like this

```
var res: Result<Int>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not written in the enum part of the Swift documentation, it's in generics: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179